# How to assign variable id or classname to a div in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a rating system using ReactJS.

my code is as follows -
This is the essential code in my **ReviewCard Component**. 
This basically returns a div where the review, username,and rating would be displayed.

```
starfunc(){
document.querySelector('.stars-inner').style.width = starPercentageRounded;
}

render(){
<h1 className="rating">Rating : {review.Rating}
            <div class="stars-outer">
               <div class="stars-inner" ></div>
              </div>
            </h1>
}
```

This is my **Reviews Component**
It recieves reviews from DB, and for each review, maps in to ReviewCard Component

```
const reviewColumns = reviews ? reviews.map(review => (

        <ReviewCard review={review} styles={{backgroundColor:"black"},{padding:"5px"}} />

    )) : null;
```

The issue is that in my ReviewCard, the document.querySelector('.stars-inner') always takes the first instance of occurence. This is resulting in the only first review getting changed everytime.

Is there a way to keep the id or classname variable or unique? Or are there any other approaches i should follow?

Here is the full code

**ReviewCard**

```
class ReviewCardComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.starfunc();
  }

  starfunc() {
    var {review} = this.props;
    var rating = review.Rating
    if(rating>5){
      rating = rating/2;
    }
    al = 5;

  const starPercentage = (rating / starTotal) * 100;
  const starPercentageRounded = `${(Math.round(starPercentage / 10) * 10)}%`;
  document.querySelector(id).style.width = starPercentageRounded; 
  }


  render() {
    console.log("reviewcard",this.props);

    const {review} = this.props;
    // The CardTitle.subtitle won't render if it's null

    console.log("qwer",review.review_id);
    return (


      <div className="main">
        <div className="fline">

          <h1 className="name">{review.user_name}</h1> 


          <h1 className="rating">Rating : {review.Rating}
            <div class="stars-outer">
               <div class="stars-inner" id={review.user_name}></div>
              </div>
            </h1>

          <button className="DeleteOptions">Options</button>

        </div>

        <h2 className="reviewtext">{review.review}</h2>
        <hr/>
      </div>



    );
  }
}
```

its CSS file

```
.stars-outer {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
  }

  .stars-outer::before {
    content: "\f006 \f006 \f006 \f006 \f006";
  }

  .stars-inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
  }

  .stars-inner::before {
    content: "\f005 \f005 \f005 \f005 \f005";
    color: #f8ce0b;
  }
```

Comment: what does `starfunc` function do in this context? There might be a better way to achieve your desired behavior. Why don't you apply `style={{width: `${startPercentageRounded)px`}}` directly like this ?

Comment: Correct class to className in ReviewCard Component.

Comment: Maybe you can pass width prop to the ReviewCard component.

Comment: The star func converts the rating number into a star based system and displays it

Comment: @Chetan, I don't think it would  solve my issue. Please elaborate

Comment: So whenever you try to write a component always try to make it functional one, You can make the calculation in wherever you are mapping Review component and you can pass width as prop and simply add style in ReviewComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong :) You should not use querySelector as this accesses the real DOM element and not the React virtualDOM element; The approach is to use the React Refs system :

1. In your ReviewCard Component in the constructor put **this.review = React.createRef();**
2. In the div with class "stars-inner" put **ref={this.review}** as a prop;
3. In your componentDidMount() life cycle method use **this.review.current**.style.width to set your styles

PS: Where is your **return** for the JSX inside the render() for your ReviewCard Component ?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think the `<Review />` component would look like this:

- Please note that I've changed your `starfunc` function to arrow function to utilize `this`
- Have a `percentage` state in each `<Review />` component, by default it will be 0

```
class ReviewCardComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    percentage: 0,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.starfunc();
  }

  starfunc = () => {
    const { review } = this.props;
    const rating = review.Rating;
    const starTotal = 5;

    if (rating > 5) {
      rating = rating / 2;
    }

    const starPercentage = (rating / starTotal) * 100;
    const starPercentageRounded = Math.round(starPercentage / 10) * 10;

    this.setState({
      percentage: starPercentageRounded || 0
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { review } = this.props;
    const { percentage } = this.state;
    // The CardTitle.subtitle won't render if it's null

    console.log("qwer", review.review_id);
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <div className="fline">
          <h1 className="name">{review.user_name}</h1>

          <h1 className="rating">
            Rating : {review.Rating}
            <div class="stars-outer">
              <div class="stars-inner" id={review.user_name} style={{width: `${percentage}%`}}></div>
            </div>
          </h1>

          <button className="DeleteOptions">Options</button>
        </div>

        <h2 className="reviewtext">{review.review}</h2>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please have a look at `al = 5`, not sure tha's a typo mistake or something. Also please check carefully with your rounding calculation, I've assigned a backup incase undefined or NaN by `0`

Comment: I've also converted `var` to `const` , you should have used that instead